# Syntax error in shopping cart addition

Tags: php

When I try to add an item to the shopping cart I get "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '>' in C:\Program Files\Abyss Web Server\htdocs\added.php"

I have looked at the code to see where there might be a previous error in the script but can't find any. The message above points me to the first line of the links to other pages which is this near the end of the script

```
echo '<p><a href="shop.php">Shop</a> |
```

However, I can't find an error and am thinking that it must be somewhere else. I tried a PHP online checker as usual but found nothing.

Here is the full script.

```
<?php

session_start() ;

if ( !isset( $_SESSION[ 'user_id' ]))
{
 require ( 'login_tools.php' ) ;
 load() ;
}

$page_title = 'Cart Addition' ;
include ( 'includes/header.html' );

if ( isset( $_GET['ID'])) $id = $_GET['id'] ;

require ( '..connect_db.php' ) ;

$q = "SELECT * FROM shop WHERE item_id = $id " ;
$r = mysqli_query( $dbc , $q ) ;
if ( mysqli_num_rows( $r ) == 1 )
{ 
 $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $r , MYSQLI_ASSOC ) ;


if ( isset( $_SESSION['CART'][$id]))
{
 $_SESSION['cart'][$id]['quantity']++ ;
 echo '<p>Another '.$row["item_name"].
       'has been added to your cart</p>';
}
else
{
 $_SESSION['cart'][$id]=
 array ( 'quantity' => 1, 'price' => $row['item_price']) ;
 echo '<p>A '.$row["item_name"].
       'has been added to your cart</p>. ;
}
}

mysqli_close( $dbc ) ;

echo '<p><a href="shop.php">Shop</a> |
<a href="cart.php">View Cart</a> |
<a href="forum.php">Forum</a> |
<a href="home.php">Home</a> |
<a href="goodbye.php">Logout</a></p>' ;

include ( 'includes/footer.html' ) ;

?>
```

Comment: The syntax highlighting shows you your error

Comment: Have a look at the colour coding in the code you've posted above - it'll show you that there's an error on an earlier line. (You've not closed a string properly)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic troubleshooting and will have no value to future visitors

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<p>A '.$row["item_name"].
   'has been added to your cart</p>. ; <-- forgot closing quote
}
```